# Navigation drawer in marshmallow not shown properly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

In lollipop OS  navigation Drawer look perfect below toolbar[image]

but in marshmallow hide toolbar with gray color 
how can I resolve  [image]

my theme for Main Activity is

```
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/battary</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
     </style>
```

and Navigation theme is

```
   <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">60dp</item><!-- item       size in menu-->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Probably missing a `fitsSystemWindows` in your XML layout. Please show it

Comment: no its true in my xml file

Comment: Read that comment again. *Please show your XML Layout*

Comment: It almost looks as if it has a title bar... Try adding the following to your NavigationDrawerStyle: <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>